# Calculating probability from alternative method

Tags: probability

> There are 8 lamps in a box of which 2 are defective. We pick up and test lamps consecutively and put aside the functional lamps until we find the first defective lamp. What's the probability of finding the defective lamp in our third test?

Well, one easy way to find this is to use

$(6/8)*(5/7)*(2/6)=5/28$

I tried to reach this answer from another method.

If we denote defective lamps with $X$ and functional ones with $Y$, then we can display a permutation of the lamps like $XXXXXXYY$ so our $n(S)= \frac{8!}{1}$ and our $n(A) = \frac{7!2!}{1} (XXYXXXXY)$ so $P(A)=\frac{7!2!}{8!}=\frac{1}{4}$ which is clearly wrong. Notice that I considered functional lamps (and defective lamps) as distinct objects, thus using the permutation formula. But clearly, this is the wrong answer. One reason could be that the probabilities are not evenly distributed. Is there something I can do to come up with an answer in another way than the correct answer I wrote first?

Comment: It seems that your functional lamps are labeled by $X$ and your defective lamps with $Y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine all the orders of the $8$ lamps such that the first two are functional and the third is defective.

You've found all such orders which have the other defective lamp last, but there are equally-many in which the other defective lamp is fourth, fifth, sixth, or seventh. Thus, there are $5$ times as many orders as you were thinking of. In addition, there are only $6$ functional lamps to permute, rather than $7.$ Thus, there are $5\cdot 6!\cdot 2!$ such orders, which gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Treating the lamps as indistinguishable (other than via "defective" or not):  There are $\binom 82=28$ ways to permute the lamps without restriction, there are $5$ ways to permute them such that the first defective lamp is in the third place.  Hence the answer is $\frac 5{28}$.

Treating them as distinct we must multiply both of those terms by $6!\times 2!$ as we now must label the undefective and defective lamps.  That factor cancels in the division.